# binding data to observable collection in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

This is the class am using. Am Adding data by calling the constructor. But the value in image is not copied `IMG` variable. All other data is binded. If I change `IMG` to normal `get; set;`, then also the binding works correctly. When setting `IMG` the value is not passed to `IMG`. I dont know the reason. That is the problem. Please help with this.

```
public class ingre : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //private string ing;
    private string img { get; set; }
    //private string si;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ingre(string image, string name, string shopitem)
    {
        ING = name;
        //string image,
        IMG = image;
        SI = shopitem;

    }


    public string ING
    {
        set;
        get;
    }


    public string IMG 
    {
        get { return img; }
        set
        {
            img = IMG;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IMG");
        }

    }

    public string SI 
    {
        set;
        get;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ING + IMG;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

this is your IMG property

```
public string IMG {

    get { return img; }
    set
    {
       if(value != img)
       {
           img = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }

    }
```

**This is your NotifyPropertyChanged Method**

```
  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(
                                      [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]
                                      string   Property = null) 

{  
   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Property));        
}
```

Comment: the property changed event works correctly. the problem when i set IMG the value is not assigned to it or img

Comment: Sorry bro i read my code and forget add--->
  
if(value != img)
       {
           img = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
       }
Look my code again :)
i hope this help you

Comment: @Suhail - He just wanted to say that passing strings (that are actually Property names) are no-goes... It causes hard to find bugs if someone changes the property names (e.g. Refactoring). Use the attribute CallerMemberName instead. Also... Your IMG property will cause a stackoverflow.

Comment: @TwostedFrost : It worked like a charm. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @SuhailIsmail Great!! hahaha